# Registeting interceptors after Component registration in Castle

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, interceptor, castle, facilities

I have a facility which needs to register an interceptor and then register this interceptor against 
a subset of the components already registerd in the container Castle Kernel.

The facility lives in a separatee assembly and it is meant to be used from different 
assemblies so I cannot couple the interceptor registration with the component registration
 of each assembly that uses this facility.

Is it possible to do this?
How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the way I use facilities is like this:

```
// 1. create the container
var container = new WindsorContainer();

// 2. add all the facilities I need
container.AddFacility<SomeFacility>();
contianer.AddFacility<SomeOtherFacility>();

// 3. install all the components
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

The facilities usually either subscribe to [container events](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Container-Events.ashx), register some of their own components, or add [`ComponentModel` construction contributors](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx) that examine and augment `ComponentModel` of components being registered.

That way it can be completely transparent to components and imposes to explicit coupling between components and facility (unless you want it).

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm just discovering contributors. I didn't know they existed!